# Can I say "pretty readable"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'd like to use the word "readable" with another one, can it be "pretty"? If not, what other adjectives can be used with "readable"?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You are probably  looking for an adverb, not an adjective, to use with the adjective 'readable'. What's wrong with 'pretty' in your opinion? What are you trying to say?

Comment: It depends on what you intend ***readable*** to mean. If you're talking about a computer storage medium or device, ***easily*** would be credible, but not ***pretty*** (which is just a slang intensifier normally meaning ***very***). If you're talking about something like a *typeface* that's easy to read (discern what the actual letters are), or a technical manual (that's easy to *read and understand*) you have a lot more scope.

Comment: I want to write "these papers are pretty readable", and I just have no idea whether it is correct or rather weird and inaccurate way of emphasizing the adjective "readable" :)

Comment: The problem is that the word "pretty" is ambiguously quantifiable in the sense of "maybe somewhat less than fully" vs "fully plus". Pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use *pretty* to modify pretty much any adjective.

And yes, *pretty* is pretty informal. I would not, however, call it slang.

Answer (score 0):

If you are discussing the latest best-seller while hoisting a few beers at the bar, that's quite acceptable.

If you are critiquing an essay for your literature class, "somewhat" readable, "rather" readable and "eminently" readable are more acceptable for a highfalutin audience.

Answer (score 0):

While it's certainly acceptable to say it, I think the meaning is easy to get confused. Firstly I would probably avoid the word "readable". Something like "Legible" or "Well Written" is less ambiguous than "readable". As for the adjective "pretty" it is a choice you could make but as others have indicated it isn't the most professional sounding choice.